# Rails filter associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord

I have Posts and Comments models
Post has_many :commetns
Comment belongs_to :post
I want to retrieve ALL* Posts with comments from certain user.
(so i want to get every single post (even these ones without comments), and filter out comments to these created by certain user)

For now I have tried things like:

```
Post.all.includes(:comments).where('comments.post_id IS NULL OR comments.user_id = ?' id).references(:comments)
```

It filters out Posts comments to ones i want, but in case Post has no other comments than filtered out ones it does not return this post (obviously It gets rejected by  where clause...)

Or

```
Post.all.joins('LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.post_id = posts.id AND c.user_id = ' + sanitize(id))
```

It returns all the posts, but filtering out does not work...

Comment: Your question is very unclear right now because right now it says you want all `Post`s and then filtered by `comments.user_id` but then you are complaining that `Post`s get filtered out. Is your intended result `Post`s with comments from a certain user and all `Post`s with no comments or all `Post`s and only comments from a certain `User`?

Comment: I want all posts, I want to filter out comments, not posts. So All Posts and only comments from a certain user

Comment: I am not certain this can be accomplished in a single method chain as it involves instance level details e.g. (post.comments.user_id) which generally means it cannot be preloaded. it might be easier just to load all the posts and then all the user comments and handle this in code.

Comment: Could you show what the SQL is generated by the second query?

Comment: @TemaBolshakov the SQL generated is simple but the problem is that the comments will not be eager loaded or cached so when you iterate through the post comments it will have 2 issues 1) n + 1 2) will not retain the user_id filter and thus will return all comments. the second can be resolved by `post.comments.where(user_id: id)` but the former cannot be resolved by an eager loaded association in this case

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no elegant solution for this problem. It's possible to preload association with static filter, e.g.:

```
User.eager_load(:popular_comments)
```

but it doesn't work with dynamic filer.

You can find excellent article about preloading Rails associations here   http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

Comment: well, Author says "What should we do when we only know at runtime about the association conditions that we would like to apply? I honestly don’t know. Please tell me in the comments if you found it out." and that is exactly my case...